# Marketing Cloud Web Collect - 200 OK but displaying "An error occurred updating the data extension"

Tags: marketing-cloud

Basically we use Web Collect on our project but for testing sake, we try to include the form parameters in the URL to pass the inputs to the Data Extension (yes, DE and not List)

We're using the url: 
http://cl.s7.exct.net/DEManager.aspx

and then adding the parameters just like this:
http://cl.s7.exct.net/DEManager.aspx?_clientID=12323&_deExternalKey=Signups_EK&_action=add&_returnXML=0&Email_address=xxx%40xx.xxx

The page displays "An error occurred updating the data extension" but when I print the http code, I got http_code 200.

In the DE Setup, none is set to primary key so the data could get in without any constraint.

The target DE has the External Key = Signups_EK and all fields are text with 254 character limit (a test DE)

Comment: Please update your question with details about the target data extension -- field sizes and data types.

Comment: hi there, I've edited it now.

Comment: Any non-nullable fields?

Comment: none, all are nullable for test. thanks for accommodating my question

Comment: @AdamSpriggs can we actually add a row to the DE via this method?

Comment: When you log into SFMC, do you see `s7` in your browser URL?

Comment: yes, and it's the only instance we are using.

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? Or did you have to try another method? I am struggling with the same issue